# How many ways are there to Read Satoshi era Wallets?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development, development, satoshi-nakamoto, wallet-of-satoshi

I've come acrossed a few -

running the original Satoshi v.0.1.0 through v.0.1.5 Clients all the way up to Satoshi v.0.7.x - I believe all of these can read Original Satoshi Wallet.dat(s) -

I have a Satoshi v.0.8.6 Client that does have the Coin-Generation Feature enabled - though I have to set it in the Bitcoin.conf file or through the Debug Console - either way - it works.  It can generate the past transactions and any rewards mined with the default (gen=0) - though, it cannot read the keys correctly.  So sending and receiving is null.  And, signing raw transactions is also null.

The third option I'm aware of.  Is running BitcoinSV - but, I'm unsure at the moment, as to whether or not, BitcoinSV Node or Lite Wallet, can generate the Ungenerated Rewards mined under the Gen=0 default coin-generation setting.  Which is what I'm looking for.

So, I'm planning to run my Wallet.dat(s) with Satoshi v.0.8.6 and generating any passed transactions and/or rewards - then running them in a BitcoinSV Node or Lite Wallet, then dumping the Private Keys - then importing the Private Keys into a Satoshi v.0.8.6 or more recent release.  Then, figuring out the routine for Wrapped Bitcoin, BCH, and other Forked Reward Blockchains.

I'd prefer it if the Bitcoin Developer Teams - tried to reproduce the Problem I'm seeing.  And fixed it - as I'd like to access all of my Mined Rewards and Received Bitcoin.  Though, I literally just get slapped with "It's impossible" then effectively banned from asking or answering anything else.  What should I do?  Does anyone else have this problem?

Bitcoin Security - literally was Privacy Security - Not Wallet Security.
Sounds like theres a scam in the making.  Specially with CSW suing the Developers to fork all Dormant coins over to him.  I have what I believe is the Genesis Block reward, which makes me remember helping whoever it was, I believe it was CSW - do to conversations I had with said developer/software programmer.  And, I would claim I created the idea, and worked with someone on it, who disagreed with my ideas, and that person decided to make it this way, rather than my way - but overall the general technology works - and I made it opensource slash freeware - doubt I can do much now - but, ok.

First things first - help me access said Rewards and Transactions stuck in a Satoshi Era Wallet.dat - If CSW or anyone that knows CSW can ask CSW to contact me or help me, it would be appreciated -

But, before anyone decides to punish me further.

Replicate my issue, then get back to me!
Or, point me in the direction to talk to said Developers myself.

Thanks - hopefully this is addressed, rather then demoted.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach of "regenerating transactions" is unproductive and unnecessary. Every version of Bitcoin Core can import wallets created by any prior versions. From there, the node will rescan the blockchain and identify all its coins automatically.

The relevant issue is that you "cannot read the [private] keys correctly".
The apparent explanation would be that your wallet file *does not contain a copy of the relevant private keys*.

If that is the case, no developer can help with that. You are describing the system working as intended: *not your [private] keys, not your coins*.
Given that anyone can create a watch-only wallet that follows the public keys of early block rewards, "seeing those balances" is neither particularly impressive, nor evidence of having been involved in the creation of Bitcoin.